# Android Studio closes immediately after launching and opening HelloWorld project

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

I am just getting starting with the Android Kotlin Fundamentals course. I have installed Android Studio and created the HelloWorld project. However, after I closed Android Studio, I am unable to open it again.

When I launch Android Studio, the splash screen appears, then the app comes up and starts loading the HelloWorld project. In the dialog box, it reports that it is "Loading components for 'HelloWorld'" then that it is "Loading modules" and then the entire Android Studio application closes and goes away.

The idea.log file is included below

I am running Windows 10 (64 bit) and Android Studio from (android-studio-ide-191.5791312-windows.exe). The only java on my computer is version 12.0.2 (which was recommended version of the Google Kotlin Bootcamp course.

I've tried setting the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME environment variables, but that has not resolved my issue.

I've tried rebooting, uninstalling and re-installing Android Studio without success

This is the relevant information from the Windows console.

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.829]

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin>java -version
java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin>javac -version
javac 12.0.2
```

**Update**

Based on a suggestion, I uninstalled Android Studio and Java from my computer. I removed all references to Java and Android from my environment variables, rebooted, and tried a fresh standard install of Android Studio. Unfortunately, Studio simply exits and goes away as soon as I create a project. I am including screen shots of my environment variables, with detail on path, as well as the output following the Android Studio installation.

Environment Variables
[image]

Detail on Path Environment Variables
[image]

Output following Android Studio install
[image]

Last bit on install output that didn't fit on the one screen
[image]

Complete idea.log is below.

```
2019-08-29 15:28:19,001 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Found Studio home directory at: 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio' 
2019-08-29 15:28:19,001 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Looking for Android SDK at 'C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/sdk' 
2019-08-29 15:28:19,002 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Looking for Android SDK at 'C:/Program Files/Android/sdk' 
2019-08-29 15:28:19,002 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - Unable to locate SDK within the Android studio installation. 
2019-08-29 15:28:19,003 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - .startup.AndroidSdkInitializer - ANDROID_HOME environment variable: 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' 
2019-08-29 15:28:19,038 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - rd.FirstRunWizardFrameProvider - Overriding welcome frame to be resizable 
2019-08-29 15:28:19,151 [oader Pool]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader took 2530 ms 
2019-08-29 15:28:19,215 [oader Pool]   INFO - dk.ClangTidyInspectionProvider - Clang-tidy inspection is enabled.} 
2019-08-29 15:28:20,262 [oader Pool]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader took 1110 ms 
2019-08-29 15:28:20,799 [oader Pool]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader took 536 ms 
2019-08-29 15:28:20,808 [oader Pool]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - com.intellij.ide.actions.GotoClassPresentationUpdater took 8 ms 
2019-08-29 15:28:22,216 [rImpl Pool]   WARN - ess.util.ProgressIndicatorBase - This progress indicator is indeterminate, this may lead to visual inconsistency. Please call setIndeterminate(false) before you start progress.
com.intellij.util.download.impl.FileDownloaderImpl$ConcurrentTasksProgressManager.updateFraction(FileDownloaderImpl.java:339) 
2019-08-29 15:28:24,705 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 166 project components initialized in 500 ms 
2019-08-29 15:28:24,706 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2019-08-29 15:28:24,774 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 3.5.0 
2019-08-29 15:28:24,788 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 3.5.0 
2019-08-29 15:28:24,790 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Subscribing project 'Project 'C:\Users\XXXX\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3' My Application' to indexing suspender events (com.android.tools.idea.project.IndexingSuspender@6632463a) 
2019-08-29 15:28:24,792 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: TEMPLATE_RENDERING_STARTED 
2019-08-29 15:28:24,792 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - a.gradle.util.BatchUpdatesUtil - Starting batch update for project: Project 'C:\Users\XXXX\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3' My Application 
2019-08-29 15:28:24,813 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 3.5.0 
2019-08-29 15:28:25,447 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Initialized from default code style settings. 
2019-08-29 15:28:25,499 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/build.gradle 
2019-08-29 15:28:25,554 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/settings.gradle 
2019-08-29 15:28:25,578 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/gradle.properties 
2019-08-29 15:28:25,693 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/local.properties 
2019-08-29 15:28:25,767 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/settings.gradle 
2019-08-29 15:28:25,797 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle 
2019-08-29 15:28:25,884 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/myapplication/ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt 
2019-08-29 15:28:25,918 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/src/test/java/com/example/myapplication/ExampleUnitTest.kt 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,310 [e-1483-b03]   WARN - templates.RepositoryUrlManager - RepositoryUrlManager#getLibraryRevision called from the UI thread. Using local cache to avoid network requests 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,318 [e-1483-b03]   WARN - templates.RepositoryUrlManager - RepositoryUrlManager#getLibraryRevision called from the UI thread. Using local cache to avoid network requests 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,318 [e-1483-b03]   WARN - templates.RepositoryUrlManager - RepositoryUrlManager#getLibraryRevision called from the UI thread. Using local cache to avoid network requests 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,318 [e-1483-b03]   WARN - templates.RepositoryUrlManager - RepositoryUrlManager#getLibraryRevision called from the UI thread. Using local cache to avoid network requests 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,319 [e-1483-b03]   WARN - templates.RepositoryUrlManager - RepositoryUrlManager#getLibraryRevision called from the UI thread. Using local cache to avoid network requests 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,319 [e-1483-b03]   WARN - templates.RepositoryUrlManager - RepositoryUrlManager#getLibraryRevision called from the UI thread. Using local cache to avoid network requests 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,322 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,498 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/MainActivity.kt 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,518 [e-1483-b03]   WARN - templates.RepositoryUrlManager - RepositoryUrlManager#getLibraryRevision called from the UI thread. Using local cache to avoid network requests 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,520 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: C:/Users/Ryan.RYANW10/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build.gradle 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,537 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: TEMPLATE_RENDERING_FINISHED 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,537 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - a.gradle.util.BatchUpdatesUtil - Finishing batch update for project: Project 'C:\Users\XXXX\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3' My Application 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,758 [e-1483-b03]   INFO - artup.AndroidStudioInitializer - Failed to disable 'org.intellij.plugins.intelliLang.inject.groovy.GrConcatenationInjector' 
2019-08-29 15:28:26,870 [d thread 2]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found
```

[threadDump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10QlDCkoI07iCoaUPv5CqRf1DZE7AXrrh/view?usp=sharing) file is too large to include in the text, so I've linked to it

Comment: You can find `error log` of `android studio` in `C:\Users\<yourid>\.AndroidStudioPreview\system\log`

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the question to include the log information

Comment: Set these env variables `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

Comment: @AbuNoman I've updated the ANDROID_HOME variable to point to the correct location, but Studio still closes as soon as it opens the project. I've updated the post to show the new log.

Comment: Follow the [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables) carefully. It seems env variable related issue. Make sure you have dowloaded SDK properly.

Comment: I've reviewed the documentation for the environment variables and don't see anything wrong. I've set the ANDROID_HOME environment accordingly, and I see that Studio is using the JVM that came packaged with it, not the Java 12 that is installed on my machine. So I don't know what else, environment variable wise, that I could be missing.

Comment: I feel it's really irritating problem to you and you have tried many ways to solve it, but no luck :'(. Do another try and see what happens. 
1. Delete `C:\Program Files\Android`, `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android`, `C:\Users\XXX\.android` and `C:\Users\XXXX\AndroidStudioProjects` folders
2. Uninstall Java and remove all env variables related to Java and Android
3. Follow installation steps given by forum [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install).

Comment: It is incredibly frustrating! And I really appreciate your patience and continued suggestions. Unfortunately, I've tried those three steps, deleting all folders, uninstalling Java and Android Studio, removing all references to them from the env vars, and following the video installation, and Android Studio still just automatically exits after I create a new project. I've added screen shots and the complete idea.log to the original post. The only new thing I've seen is a thread stack dump log out of Android Studio, so I've uploaded that as well.

Comment: This is very strange, I've got access to a loaner Windows 10 laptop. Went through the install, created my app, ran it through the emulator. Then I rebooted the machine, launched Android Studio. It comes up, loads the components, the modules, and then just closes and goes away. So if there's something environmental, then it must exist on that laptop as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android folder, and C:\Users\xxx.AndroidStudiox.x, and reopen and install anything it says that you need to install (sdk's), that may fix your issue.

I suspect this based on this line here:

INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I deleted both those folders, and Studio had me download and re-install the sdk and some other tools. However, it still just closes after creating a project. The '0 startup script(s) found' line is still present in the idea.log file.